Getting negative probabilities in the count result
I am struggling with a very basic concept.
What exactly is the negative probability means in count result?
When I run a circuit without error mitigation and with error mitigation using a really great code from the question: How to save and retrieve results of m3_mitigator.cals_from_system API
 counts: {'110': 3, '101': 12, '100': 6, '010': 1, '000': 485, '011': 10, '111': 475, '001': 8}   
  
mitigated_counts: {'000': 0.4997268815983746, '001': 0.0018235803591897181, '010': -0.003462290103489802, '011': 0.003701377179569034, '100': 0.0016733138269399825, '101': 0.002538726788041519, '110': -0.0005898841059944805, '111': 0.49458829445736946}

Should I take a modulus of the probability and ignore the negative sign?  Thank you great and continuous help.

Here's an explanation on negative values you mentioned.

Closest probability distribution The results of M3 mitigation are
quasi-probabilities that nominally contain small negative values. This
is suitable for use in computing corrected expectation values or
sampling problems where one is interested in the highest probability
bit-string. However, if one needs a true probability distribution then
it is possible to convert from quasi-probabilites to the closest true
probability distribution in L2-norm using:
closest_probs = m3_quasi.nearest_probability_distribution()

So, according to that guide, this code will probably do to convert to a true probability distribution :
mitigated_counts = m3_mitigator_loaded.apply_correction(counts, meas_mapping_loaded)
probs = mitigated_counts.nearest_probability_distribution()
print(probs)


Thank you @takrtoshikinoshita for this great great help.
